# Unit testing backpropagation neural network code

Tags: unit-testing, neural-network, backpropagation

I am writing a backprop neural net mini-library from scratch and I need some help with writing meaningful automated tests. Up until now I have automated tests that verify that weight and bias gradients are calculated correctly by the backprop algorithm, but no test on whether the training itself actually works.

The code I have up until now lets me do the following:

- Define a neural net with any number of layers and neurons per layer.
- It can use any layer activation functions.
- Using biases is also possible.
- Layers of neurons can only be fully connected at the moment.
- Training is only BP with gradient descent.
- Must use train, validation and test sets (none of these sets can be empty at the moment).

Given all of these, what kind of automated test can I write to ensure that the training algorithm is implemented correctly. What function (sin, cos, exp, quadratic, etc) should I try to approximate? In what range and how densely should I sample data from this function? What architecture should the NN have?

Ideally, the function should be fairly simple to learn so the test wouldn't last very long (1-3 seconds), but also complicated enough to provide some degree of certainty that the algorithm is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm in the middle of doing something similar for my degree. What you are looking for is integration tests, not unit tests.

Unit test only tells you if the code works the way you want it to. To check if the algorithm actually works correctly, you should write integration tests where you create your network with all the needed dependencies (real, not mocks).

Having created a network, you can simply try to perform learning. Test of simple mathematical functions are good for start. For more dimensional functions you can try e.q. [Rosenbrock function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function). It's very nice, as you can change it's dimensionality with just one parameter. I used it only for GA benchmarks though.

You can also test it on real data sets. I recommend [Iris Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris). It's quite small and easy to learn. If the tests pass you can see that your network really works, not just solves a mathematical function. I personally find it comforting. :)

To make sure your tests do not run too long set a reasonable max epochs number. Also note that you want your test to pass every time until you mess something up, so do not make them too hard to pass.

As far as I remember I use 10 hidden neurons for iris dataset. Within about 5 iterations you should be able to easily get at least 95% of correct answers.

Such tests may take a few seconds, but it's good to have some. You do not have to run them every time. But if you do a massive refactoring and they still pass you just do not have to worry. Trust me - I've been there.

Comment: Thanks for recommending Iris Dataset! One more question. What gradient descent factor are you using to get good results in 5 iterations? With a factor of 0.2 it takes me around 600 iterations to stop. (The stopping condition is that the validation set error should start increasing. I don't have any early stops implemented at this point.)

Comment: @PaulManta By single iteration I mean putting all of the training patterns through the network (150 patterns in data set * 5 iterations = 750 network circulations). I use adaptive speed factor. I start with 0.5. If error decreases i multiply it by 1.01. If error increases I multiply it by 0.5.

Comment: That is also what I meant by a single iteration (so I actually have `600 * 150` circulations). I don't have an adaptive speed factor, so that might have something to do with it. Anyway, thank you for your help! I now feel confident that the code is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Neural Network components actually make for an excellent opportunity for unit testing. The thing to keep in mind is "what behavior are we sure this software should exhibit?". Some key points to verify, which I discuss in more detail in [my blog post](http://blog.simiacryptus.com/2017/12/unit-testing-and-neural-networks.html), are:

1. Finite Difference Validation - test the consistency of the back-propagation operation with the component's function - as it should be the analytic derivative, it should agree with a numeric approximation of the derivative.
2. Serialization
3. Consistency with Reference Implementation (if any) - This is valuable when you are implementing the same function multiple times, such as GPU-acceleration or FFT-based convolution.
4. Performance and additional smoke testing, as appropriate.

Of course integration tests using well known test problems are an indispensable compliment, which I cover in my [subsequent post](http://blog.simiacryptus.com/2017/12/test-driven-development-for-neural-nets.html), but your question asked about unit tests.